# SQL Server CE 4 - how to select n random rows from a table?

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

Does anyone have a query that will select n number of random rows from a SQL Server CE 4 table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT TOP N * FROM table ORDER BY NEWID()
```

NEWID causes a GUID (semi-random identifier) to be created for each row in the result set and sorting by it ought to give you N fairly random results.

Comment: I thought I'd tried `NEWID()` before I asked the question and it didn't work, so I presumed it wasn't available with CE. I've just tried it again though and it works perfectly, so I was obviously making a silly mistake elsewhere. Thanks for the help!